# How to un-commit all un-pushed git commits without losing the changes

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-pull

Is there any way to undo all un-pushed commits (I made 3 commits to the wrong branch without pushing) without losing the changes?

Comment: ```git reset --mixed HEAD~3``` can un-commit your changes but keep them.

Comment: @buladepite 
Thank you it solved,how i can move to the correct branch and keep the changes locally until i commit them again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+pushed+commits

Comment: @Alaa what do you mean by "keep you changes locally"? Are you trying to replay the changes on the correct branch? You can "git stash" the changes on the wrong branch and "git stash apply" on the correct branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git reset` to get back to previous commits.

Make sure to use the --mixed option, so it keeps your changes but removes the commits:

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~3
```

Comment: I don't see how this necessarily helps the OP, since your answer would still leave the uncommitted work on the wrong branch.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually suggest in this case is to just create a new branch from your current commit, and then hard reset the current branch back to the point before you made the new commits.

```
# from master
git branch feature
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

The above assumes that you mistakingly made your commits to the `master` branch, when you actually intended to be on some `feature` branch.  It also assumes that you made 3 commits.  Change the hard reset command to the correct number of commits if not 3.

Answer (score 1):

`~1` `~2` `~3` `~4` is number of commits

Delete the most recent commits, keeping changes

```js
git reset --soft HEAD~4
```

Delete the most recent commit, deleting changes

```js
git reset --hard HEAD~4
```

Keeps changes but removes the commits

```js
git reset --mixed HEAD~4
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a way to do this without always needing to know how many commits to reset. So to automatically get that number I used `git cherry -v`, which provides this kind of data:

```
+ 5863a345c61f9940415899ef1a3d4af61d81c350 fix no color causing broken swatch
+ 4d777fee2e46a49e6d1c7c293246eb0a6e7a9a40 better support for categories without a default color
```

Pipe that through `wc -l` to get a line count and then through `xargs` to cleanup whitespace and...:

```
git reset --mixed "HEAD~$(git cherry -v | wc -l | xargs)"
```